# Why slash search doesn't work in man pages?

Tags: linux, terminal, less, ubuntu-20.04, manpage

After opening the a man page, the slash search does not work.
I type `/` but there is no reaction from the man.
If i open any file in vim slash search will work.

EDIT:

````
  $ update-alternatives --display pager

  pager - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/less
  link currently points to /usr/bin/less
  link pager is /usr/bin/pager
  slave pager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz
/bin/more - priority 50
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
/usr/bin/less - priority 77
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default pager for man pages is less (<kbd>/</kbd> to search). Check your current pager configuration:

```
update-alternatives --display pager
```

Change it

```
update-alternatives --config pager
```

Comment: I already have less as default

Comment: What about other keys, `h` or `?`?

Comment: `h` and `?` work fine

Comment: oh it was num lock issue. it was turned off.